# t-SQL query complex rolling months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Requirement is that, we need records for below 'production_date':

**today='2015-08-06 00:00:00.000'.**

As of today, production_date's in **JULY** only.

And in **SEPT**, production_date's from **JULY** AND **AUGUST**.

In **OCT**, production_date's from **JULY, AUGUST and SEPT** ..and so on..

**BUT once in** **JAN 2016**, production_date's from **last 6 months** only.

This means from **FEB 2016**, productions_date's from **AUG 2015 TO JAN 2016**

additonal info:

Production_date is a date column. And i'm filtering records based on above condition.

I tried:

Production_Date > DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(m,DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()),0),'2016-01-01 00:00:00.000')-6,GETDATE())), 0)

**AND**

Production_Date< DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

Please let me know how to go about gettting this in a query.

Comment: What do you want? A query or a custom function? Did you attempt anything? Can you give an example of how you'll use this?

Comment: hi Emacs, I wanted a query with expression that can filter on above condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT  columnlist
FROM    table
WHERE   ProductionDate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -6,
                                  DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()),
                                          0))
        AND ProductionDate < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
        AND ProductioNDate >= '2015-07-01'
```

Comment: Thanks!  please mark it as the answer if it solved your problem.